# HierarchyRequestError with jquery .wrap()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot figure why I got this error in chrome :

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
```

Same in firefox :

```
HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

Here is my js :

```
// Applies wrapper to lists
$('#content .portlet-body').find('ul').each(function() {
    var content = $(this);
    if ( !content.hasClass('dropdown-menu') && !content.hasClass('nav') && !content.hasClass('lfr-discussion-actions') && !content.hasClass('tree-view-content') ) {
        content.wrap('<div class="floating-list"></div>');
    }
});
```

The purpose of this piece of code is to wrap specific `ul` lists between a wrapper div with special class. Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Unable to replicate; the code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqtt6kyw/ Are you sure this is the block raising the error?

Comment: When I put the code in comments, the error goes out. So I believe this is it. I also have other pieces of code. But none uses any `replace`, or `clone` or `wrap` function. A few use `appendTo` and `append`, but nothing wrong with em at first look.